# Copy XPages Themes

Tags: themes, xpages, lotus, ibm-oneui

I would like to copy the XPages themes in the Teamroom application to my own application but it has not worked. I just copied an dpasted the themes files but the browser will not display and page using one of the copied themes. What else must I do to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Not looked into the theme, but there might be an dependency on css files and image resources as well. So you have to copy these files to your application, too. In addition, you have to set the application properties to use the theme. And, you have to give your design elements the appropriate theme.id in its property.

Comment: If you haven't already, enable the default error page; assuming you've set the application to use the copied theme but have not brought over the dependent resources, the error page will tell you which resource it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the Application Properties to use one of the themes you pasted into your app? Sorry if you have but not mentioned that in your question.